# How to count all distinguishable subsets with repeated elements?

Tags: set, combinations, permutation, subset, discrete-mathematics

Say you have a list of elements, with some repeats: [1,2,2,3,3,3,4] and you want to count all distinguishable sets of at most the set's length.  E.g. {1,2,2,3,3,4} and {1,2,3,4} are counted but we don't want to multi-count {1,2,3,4}.  How would you do this?

My thinking was you'd have 2^7 non-unique sets and you could subtract or divide to find uniques.  But I couldn't think of the right approach.

Or maybe you could treat the problem as putting the elements in 2 different bags and use the multinomial theorem but I'm not sure how to set that up either.

Answer (score 1):

You can take zero or one 1 from the set (2 choices); zero through two 2's from the set (3 choices); zero through three 3's (4 choices); and zero or one 4 (2 choices), giving you 2 * 3 * 4 * 2 = 48 different sets.